# sequelize table without column 'id'

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following sequelize definition of a table:

```
AcademyModule = sequelize.define('academy_module', {
        academy_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        module_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        module_module_type_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        sort_number: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        requirements_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true
});
```

As you can see there is not an `id` column in this table. However when I try to insert it still tries the following sql:

```
 INSERT INTO `academy_module` (`id`,`academy_id`,`module_id`,`sort_number`) VALUES (DEFAULT,'3',5,1);
```

How can I disable the `id` function it clearly has?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

If you don't define a `primaryKey` then sequelize uses `id` by default.

If you want to set your own, just use `primaryKey: true` on your column.

```
AcademyModule = sequelize.define('academy_module', {
    academy_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    module_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    module_module_type_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    sort_number: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    requirements_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
}, {
    freezeTableName: true
});
```

Comment: What if both module_id and academy_id is a primaryKey?

Comment: A table can only have one primary key, unless you create a compound primary key. I'm not sure if Sequelize supports this.

Comment: Disregard the above, Sequelize does support this. Just add `primaryKey: true` to the columns you want to use as a primary key.

Comment: how to delare primary key using sequelize-cli like something like this sequelize model:create --name MyUsera --attributes first_name:Integer:primaryKey: true,last_name:string,bio:text

Comment: Why is this even regarded as an answer? The question was very clearly "How can i disable the `id` function it clearly has?" and this answer tries to answer it with "If you want you can change the name of the primary key". What??

Comment: Maybe you should read the answer as: 'Your tables MUST have a primary key, so it cannot be disabled, but you can change the name/definition of it'. Not sure whether it's actually impossible to completely disable it though.

Comment: According to [sequelize configurtion](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/#configuration), one can define which of the existing/defined fields will be the `id` (you can set multiple filds as `primaryKey: true`) and if you have just no id on your table, then [sequelize legazy](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/legacy/) documentation says you can just remove it with `Model.removeAttribute('id');` and you will have a table (model) without primary key.

Answer (score 66):

If you want to completely disable the primary key for the table, you can use `Model.removeAttribute`. Be warned that this could cause problems in the future, as Sequelize is an ORM and joins will need extra setup.

```
const AcademyModule = sequelize.define('academy_module', {
    academy_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    module_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    module_module_type_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    sort_number: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    requirements_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
}, {
    freezeTableName: true
});
AcademyModule.removeAttribute('id');
```

Comment: That is, unless you want to join to a non-primary key column with a unique index

Answer (score 25):

If your model does not have an ID column you can use Model.removeAttribute('id'); to get rid of it.

See http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/legacy/

So in your case it would be

```
AcademyModule = sequelize.define('academy_module', {
    academy_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    module_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    module_module_type_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    sort_number: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    requirements_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
}, {
    freezeTableName: true
});
AcademyModule.removeAttribute('id');
```

**Note:**
You seem to be making a join table. Consider making `academy_id` *and* `module_id` primary keys. That way the same link will not be able to appear multiple times, and the database will not create a hidden id column in vain.

Answer (score 20):

For a composite primary key, you should add "primaryKey: true" to all columns part of the primary key. Sequelize considers such columns to be part of a composite primary key.

Comment: how to delare custome primary key using sequelize-cli like something like this sequelize model:create --name MyUsera --attributes first_name:Integer:primaryKey: true,last_name:string,bio:text

Comment: This was back in 2015 and I can't figure out what is going on. How do I build the relationships with a compound key??

Comment: OP has asked for "How can I disable the id function it clearly has?" this is clearly the wrong answer.

Comment: You're right. OP would have marked this as an answer if this was the direct unblocking solution. This extends the right answer for cases where the primary key is composite. You clearly have not read the solution Ben Fortune provided.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are using sequelize cli to generate models, removeAttribute to be written like below

```
    module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class follow extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  }
  follow.init({
    follower_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    followee_id: DataTypes.INTEGER
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'follows',
  });

  follow.removeAttribute("id");

  return follow;
};
```