# After importing data into MySQL, Sequelize give error "Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'"

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

The table was created by Sequelize. Then I imported data into that table from an .sql file with Workbench.

Now Sequelize throws "Unknown column 'id' in 'field list'" when I try to create an entry.

'id' is defined in the table as the primary key:

[MySQL workbench screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1GRB.png)

Can I alter the table to get it to work with Sequelize?

Example of model:

```
var Record = sequelize.define("Record", {
        secondaryID: {
            type: DataTypes.UUID,
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true,
            autoIncrement: false
        },
        description: DataTypes.STRING(1024),
        title: DataTypes.STRING,
        documentType: DataTypes.STRING,
        /*About 80 variables of the STRING type*/
        });
```

Comment: share your model

Comment: Ok, model added.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sequelize table without column 'id'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29233896/sequelize-table-without-column-id)